# C TCP sockets, can 'send' return 0 after using select?

Tags: c, sockets, select, asynchronous, client-server

I have a client-server program in c.
I'm using select to ensure that the client is ready to accept data, (i.e. - client_fd is in write_fds returned by select).
If the client is indeed ready to accept data, can I be sure that if I send to this client (using the c method 'send', and number of bytes to be sent is > 0), the number of bytes actually sent (==returned by 'send') is at least 1 byte? or 0 is still possible?

thanks

*note that the client is connected to only one server and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero is never possible. It will either transfer at least one byte and return the cost, or return -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` if the buffer is full in non-blocking mode, or -1 with some other `errno` if there is a bad error. It shouldn't give `-1/EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` if `select()` has indicated otherwise, except in the presence of multithreaded writing to the socket.

Comment: Well, technically wrong. There are more than those two errors listed above which can trigger send to return -1. The most important would be, of course, the socket being closed on the other side.

Comment: Of course there are more than those two errors. The answer is about the situation referred to in the question.

Comment: citation needed.